# How can I execute some async tasks in parallel with limit in generator function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, parallel-processing, async.js

I'm trying to execute some async tasks **in parallel** with a limitation on the **maximum number** of simultaneously running tasks.

There's an example of what I want to achieve:

[image: Task flow example]

Currently this tasks are running one after another. It's implemented this way:

```js
export function signData(dataItem) {
  cadesplugin.async_spawn(async function* (args) {
    //... nestedArgs assignment logic ...

    for (const id of dataItem.identifiers) {
      yield* idHandler(dataItem, id, args, nestedArgs);
    }
    
    // some extra logic after all tasks were finished
  }, firstArg, secondArg);
}

async function* idHandler(edsItem, researchId, args, nestedArgs) {
  ...
  let oDocumentNameAttr = yield cadesplugin.CreateObjectAsync("CADESCOM.CPAttribute");
  yield oDocumentNameAttr.propset_Value("Document Name");
  ...
  // this function mutates some external data, making API calls and returns void
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't make any changes in `cadesplugin.*` functions, but I can use any external libraries (or built-in `Promise`) in my code.

I found some methods ([eachLimit](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#eachLimit) and [parallelLimit](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#parallelLimit)) in **async** library that might work for me and [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37526207/how-to-use-async-parallellimit-to-maximize-the-amount-of-paralle-running-proce) that shows how to deal with it.

But there are still two problems I can't solve:

1. How can I pass main params into nested function?
2. Main function is a **generator function**, so I still need to work with **yield** expressions in main and nested functions

There's a link to [cadesplugin.* source code](https://www.cryptopro.ru/sites/default/files/products/cades/cadesplugin_api.js), where you can find **async_spawn** (and another `cadesplugin.*`) function that used in my code.

That's the code I tried with no luck:

```js
await forEachLimit(dataItem.identifiers, 5, yield* async function* (researchId, callback) { 
  //... nested function code 
});
```

It leads to **Object is not async iterable** error.

Another attempt:

```js
let functionArray = [];
dataItem.identifiers.forEach(researchId => {
  functionArray.push(researchIdHandler(dataItem, id, args, nestedArgs))
});
await parallelLimit(functionArray, 5);
```

It just does nothing.

Сan I somehow solve this problem, or the generator functions won't allow me to do this?

Comment: i think you will find [this q&a](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67628301/633183) to be helpful. let me know if you have follow up questions ^_^

Comment: A promise aware map with concurrency option sounds like something you could use, bluebird has a concurrency option, but instead of a large promise lib, something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise.map might be ideal.

Comment: @Mulan, @Keith, thanks for your comments, but unfortunately I'm still not quietly understand how to mix custom `Pool` or bluebird's `Promise.map` with generator functions and yield expressions... My attempts with these solutions still leads to "Object is not async iterable" or "doing nothing" errors. I would be very grateful if you could suggest something about this

Comment: @AlexanderShkirkov, I have written a custom eachlimit function, which does the same thing you were asking, have a look and let me know if it is helpful ,https://jsfiddle.net/devnegikec/k3a20qvt/38/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**square peg, round hole**

You cannot use async iterables for this problem. It is the nature of `for await .. of` to run *in series*. `await` blocks and the loop will not continue until the awaited promise has resovled. You need a more precise level of control where you can enforce these specific requirements.

To start, we have a mock `myJob` that simulates a long computation. More than likely this will be a network request to some API in your app -

```js
// any asynchronous task
const myJob = x =>
  sleep(rand(5000)).then(_ => x * 10)
```

Using `Pool` defined in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67628301/633183), we instantiate `Pool(size=4)` where `size` is the number of concurrent threads to run -

```js
const pool = new Pool(4)
```

For ergonomics, I added a `run` method to the `Pool` class, making it easier to wrap and run jobs -

```js
class Pool {
  constructor (size) ...
  open () ...
  deferNow () ...
  deferStacked () ...

  // added method
  async run (t) {
    const close = await this.open()
    return t().then(close)
  }
}
```

Now we need to write an effect that uses our `pool` to run `myJob`. Here you will also decide what to do with the result. Note the promise **must** be wrapped in a thunk otherwise pool cannot control when it begins  -

```js
async function myEffect(x) {
  // run the job with the pool
  const r = await pool.run(_ => myJob(x))

  // do something with the result
  const s = document.createTextNode(`${r}\n`)
  document.body.appendChild(s)

  // return a value, if you want
  return r
}
```

Now run everything by mapping `myEffect` over your list of inputs. In our example `myEffect` we `return r`  which means the result is also available after *all* results are fetched. This optional but demonstrates how program knows when everything is done -

```js
Promise.all([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12].map(myEffect))
  .then(JSON.stringify)
  .then(console.log, console.error)
```

**full program demo**

In the functioning demo below, I condensed the definitions so we can see them all at once. Run the program to verify the result in your own browser -

```js
class Pool {
  constructor (size = 4) { Object.assign(this, { pool: new Set, stack: [], size }) }
  open () { return this.pool.size < this.size ? this.deferNow() : this.deferStacked() }
  run (t) { return this.open().then(close => t().then(close)) }
  deferNow () { const [t, close] = thread(); const p = t.then(_ => this.pool.delete(p)).then(_ => this.stack.length && this.stack.pop().close()); this.pool.add(p); return Promise.resolve(close) }
  deferStacked () { const [t, close] = thread(); this.stack.push({ close }); return t.then(_ => this.deferNow()) }
}
const rand = x => Math.random() * x
const effect = f => x => (f(x), x)
const thread = close => [new Promise(r => { close = effect(r) }), close]
const sleep = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))

const myJob = x =>
  sleep(rand(5000)).then(_ => x * 10)

async function myEffect(x) {
  const r = await pool.run(_ => myJob(x))
  const s = document.createTextNode(`${r}\n`)
  document.body.appendChild(s)
  return r
}
  
const pool = new Pool(4)

Promise.all([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12].map(myEffect))
  .then(JSON.stringify)
  .then(console.log, console.error)
```

**slow it down**

`Pool` above runs concurrent jobs as quickly as possible. You may also be interested in `throttle` which is also introduced in the original post. Instead of making `Pool` more complex, we can wrap our jobs using `throttle` to give the caller control over the *minimum* time a job should take -

```js
const throttle = (p, ms) =>
  Promise.all([ p, sleep(ms) ]).then(([ value, _ ]) => value)
```

We can add a `throttle` in `myEffect`. Now if `myJob` runs very quickly, at least 5 seconds will pass before the next job is run -

```js
async function myEffect(x) {
  const r = await pool.run(_ => throttle(myJob(x), 5000))
  const s = document.createTextNode(`${r}\n`)
  document.body.appendChild(s)
  return r
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! :) My main problem is still related to using generator functions in this case, but I guess now I can solve it by myself. I'll accept this answer as a more general solution, and will try to post my own answer related to `cadesplugin.*` generator functions a little bit later

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very short vanilla JS function `mapParallel` that will call `fn(v, i)` for each element of `values` while making sure that at most `max` Promises are in flight at each moment:

```
const mapParallel = async (values, fn, max=10) => {
  const promises = new Set();

  for (const i in values) {
    while (promises.size >= max)
      await Promise.race(promises.values());

    let promise = fn(values[i], i).finally(() => promises.delete(promise));
    promises.add(promise);
  }

  return Promise.all(promises.values());
};
```

By using an async function together with a regular for loop we can just block the loop using `await` until a slot has become free before kicking off each new invocation.

Sample usage, running two delays at a time:

```
mapParallel(
  [5000,2000,1000,3000,4000],
  async (t, i) => {
    console.log('starting', i);
    await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, t));
    console.log('finished', i);
  },
  2
);
```

which prints:

```
starting 0
starting 1
finished 1
starting 2
finished 2
starting 3
finished 0
starting 4
finished 3
finished 4
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. How do I get the results of the promises when they have all completed? Would it just be `let results = mapParallel(...);`

Comment: @BryanAnderson yes , except that the result is also a Promise. So in an async context you can use `const results = await mapParallel(...);`, or `mapParallel(...).then(results => { ... });` otherwise.

Comment: So when I was doing that, I was getting an incomplete result and it just seemed it was returning the actual promise, instead of the result of the function I was calling (i.e. `fetch()//get some JSON`)

Answer (score 0):

In general, it should be better to apply [@Mulan answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70475685/9275224).

But if you also stuck into `cadesplugin.*` **generator** functions and don't really care about heavyweight external libraries, this answer may also be helpful.

(If you are worried about heavyweight external libraries, you may still mix this answer with @Mulan's one)

Async task running can simply be solved using `Promise.map` function from [bluebird library](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) and double-usage of `cadesplugin.async_spawn` function.

The code will look like the following:

```js
export function signData(dataItem) {
  cadesplugin.async_spawn(async function* (args) {
    // some extra logic before all of the tasks

    await Promise.map(dataItem.identifiers,
      (id) => cadesplugin.async_spawn(async function* (args) {
        // ...
        let oDocumentNameAttr = yield cadesplugin.CreateObjectAsync("CADESCOM.CPAttribute");
        yield oDocumentNameAttr.propset_Value("Document Name");
        // ...
        // this function mutates some external data and making API calls
      }),
      {
        concurrency: 5 //Parallel tasks count
      });
    
    // some extra logic after all tasks were finished
  }, firstArg, secondArg);
}
```

The magic comes from `async_spawn` function which is defined as:

```js
function async_spawn(generatorFunction) {
  async function continuer(verb, arg) {
    let result;
    try {
      result = await generator[verb](arg);
    } catch (err) {
      return Promise.reject(err);
    }
    if (result.done) {
      return result.value;
    } else {
      return Promise.resolve(result.value).then(onFulfilled, onRejected);
    }
  }

  let generator = generatorFunction(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
  let onFulfilled = continuer.bind(continuer, "next");
  let onRejected = continuer.bind(continuer, "throw");
  return onFulfilled();
}
```

It can suspend the execution of **internal** generator functions on **yield** expressions without suspending the **whole** generator function.