# How to render images sequentially in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of image urls and would like to render the images sequentially. Here is an example of my desired output:

[image]

My current code looks something like this:

```js
function Images({ imgURLs }: { imgURLs: string[] }) {
  return (
    <div id="img-container">
      {imgURLs.map((url) => (
        <img key={url} src={url} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
</div>
```

However, this doesn't guarantee that the images will be rendered in sequence.

Comment: Loading them concurrently in batches according to order of display might be a useful optimization, but an important distinction is the difference between **(down)loading** to memory/cache and **displaying** in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

**the problem**

The images are loaded concurrently but you are attempting to display them in series. If there is a slow image near the beginning, it will prevent all later images from being displayed, even if they have loaded already. You can see the effect exaggerated in the demo below. Run the program a few times to see how varied load times affects the rendered output -

```js
function App() {
  const [images, setImages] = React.useState([])
  const loadImage = _ => sleep(Math.random() * 5000) // exaggerated load time
  React.useEffect(
    () => {
      Array
        .from(Array(100), loadImage)
        .reduce(
          (pr, pi) => pr.then(_ => pi.then(i => setImages(prev => [...prev, i]))),
          Promise.resolve()
        )
        .then(_ => console.log("done"))
        .catch(console.error)
    },
    []
  )
  return <div style={{display: "flex", flexWrap: "wrap"}}>
    {images.map((i, key) => (
      <div key={key} className="image" title={i}>{key}</div>
     ))}
  </div>
}

// deps
function sleep(ms) { return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms, ms)) }

// init
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(<App />)
```

```css
.image { font-size: .75rem; margin: .25rem; padding: .25rem; border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

StackOverflow does not support `async..await` in React snippets, otherwise we could write it more clearly -

```js
useEffect(
  () => {
    async function run() {
      for (const _ of Array(100))
        setImages(prev => [...prev, await loadImage()])
    }
    run()
      .then(_ => console.log("done"))
      .catch(console.error)
  },
  []
}
```

**a solution**

Now let's achieve the loading effect you want. We'll use a `Pool` abstraction introduced in a [previous Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70475685/633183) that gives us more control over the concurrent operations. We'll use `20` concurrent connections and a simulated ~50ms of load time for each image. And we'll show a better `async..await` version after this demo -

```js
function App() {
  const [images, setImages] = React.useState([])
  const pool = React.useRef(new Pool(20)).current
  const loadImage = _ => sleep(Math.random() * 50)
  React.useEffect(
    () => {
      let p = Promise.resolve()
      for (const _ of Array(100)) {
        p = p.then(_ => pool.run(loadImage).then(i => setImages(p => [...p, i])))
      }
      p.then(_ => console.log("done"))
      .catch(console.error)
    },
    []
  )
  return <div style={{display: "flex", flexWrap: "wrap"}}>
    {images.map((i, key) => (
      <div key={key} className="image" title={i}>{key}</div>
    ))}
  </div>
}

// dependencies
class Pool {
  constructor (size = 4) { Object.assign(this, { pool: new Set, stack: [], size }) }
  open () { return this.pool.size < this.size ? this.deferNow() : this.deferStacked() }
  run (t) { return this.open().then(close => t().then(close)) }
  deferNow () { const [t, close] = thread(); const p = t.then(_ => this.pool.delete(p)).then(_ => this.stack.length && this.stack.pop().close()); this.pool.add(p); return Promise.resolve(close) }
  deferStacked () { const [t, close] = thread(); this.stack.push({ close }); return t.then(_ => this.deferNow()) }
}
const effect = f => x => (f(x), x)
const thread = close => [new Promise(r => { close = effect(r) }), close]
const sleep = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms, ms))

// init
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(<App />)
```

```css
.image { font-size: .75rem; margin: .25rem; padding: .25rem; border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Again `async..await` makes a big difference -

```js
const pool = useRef(new Pool(20)).current

useEffect(
  () => {
    async function run() {
      for (const _ of Array(100))
        setImages(prev => [...prev, await pool.run(loadImage)]
    )
    run()
      .then(_ => console.log("done"))
      .catch(console.error)
  },
  []
)
```